# How to set the limit of the for loop to work until end of line/until specific string is reached

Tags: c, c99

So I'm basically trying to make a for loop that scans the input line. The input is always one double float number and then one string. It continues scanning until the string `=` is reached. Each number value is stored to an array of double and each string to an array of char.

Problem is that the input line can be arbitrarily long and I don't know how to make it

The program should work as a basic calculator which reads one double float, then one operator as a string, and performs operation. If another number follows, then perform the operation with this number. If the equal sign `=` is reached, the program outputs the result.

```c
int main() {
    double res;
    double in[10];
    char *op[10][5];
    int arrCheck[10];

    for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) {
        scanf("%lf %s ", &in[i], op[i]);
        arrCheck[i] = opCheck(op[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the main section of my program so far. I managed to get it working and storing the data correctly. Although it always works only on predefined limit (i<=5, for instance). Is it legal to write condition like:

`for(i = 0; i<'\n'; i++)`, or `i<=`?

I would expect it to continue scanning and storing the data until it reaches the equal sign `=`.

Comment: This code is broken from inception. `int *op[10][5]` declares an array of ten arrays of five pointers to char. therefore `op[i]` evaluates as an array of five pointer-to-char, which in no way matches the type of `%s` claimed in the format string.

Comment: The loop test `i<'\n';` is legal but probably won't do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; (i <= 5) && (strcmp(op[i], "=") != 0); i++) {
...
}
```

And on your question, it is not legal to compare integers with strings. This is why string comparing functions exist.

You can also break from `for` loop like this:

```
int main()
{
    double res;
    double in[10];
    char op[10][5];
    int arrCheck[10];

    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        scanf("%lf %s ", &in[i], op[i]);
        if (strcmp(op[i], "=") == 0)
            break;
        arrCheck[i] = opCheck(op[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which is even better solution than the one posted previously.

Comment: Hello, thanks very much for answer! This looks really useful. Though, actually the i<=5 condition was just an orientational and the condition should be that the loop should always end when = is reached. Do you think I could use the strcmp() condition together with the break condition within the loop?

Comment: @DemoVision Please explain your question. I do not follow you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading with `scanf` and the `"%s"` *conversion-specifier*, you will consume leading whitespace before each operator stored in `op[n]`. There is no need to call `strcmp`, you can simply check the first character by dereferencing the pointer, e.g.

```
        if (scanf ("%lf %s", &in[i], op[i]) != 2 || *op[i] == '=') 
            break;
```

A short example omitting `opCheck(op[i])` not included in your question, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    double in[10];
    char op[10][5];
    int i = 0, n;

    while (i < 10) {
        if (scanf ("%lf %s", &in[i], op[i]) != 2 || *op[i] == '=') 
            break;
        i++;
    }
    n = ++i;

    puts ("\nequation: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" %g %s", in[i], op[i]);
    puts (" res");
}
```

(**note:** the use of `while (i < 10)` rather than a `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)`. You do not want to increment `i` in case of a *matching* or *input* failure. You only increment `i` after validating both conversions succeeded)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/eqnread
5.1 + 6 - 2 + 25 * 4 =

equation:
 5.1 + 6 - 2 + 25 * 4 = res
```

Comment: Hi! Many thanks, I've tried with a while loop and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm basically trying to make a for loop that scans the input *line*. The input is always one double float number and then one string.

If you care about *lines* specifically (which are ended by `\n` -or by `\r` on *some* [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)), you cannot use [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *alone*, because `scanf` deals with all kind of space characters (including the space, the tabulation, the newline, the formfeed characters) in the same way, so ignores the specificity of end of line characters (`\n` and/or `\r`).

So the good way is to *read the entire line* first with [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (or [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) on Linux) and later to [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) that line. Be careful about very long lines, they could happen.

How would you parse that read line is a different question: manual [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and parsing, or `sscanf`, or [strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) or [strtod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof), etc... come to mind.

And you did not define what a string is for you. What about spaces inside it? What about input lines that are longer than what you expect (e.g. a line of a thousand characters)? The `%s` for `scanf` would stop at the first space.

Don't forget to read *carefully* the documentation of every used function. Learn [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Be also aware that, practically speaking, in 2019 [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is [used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/), and that may add complications to your scheme (and to what strings are in practice).

> The program should work as a basic calculator

It seems that you then should care about [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). Then, [recursive descent parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) comes to mind.